# Make the back button scroll the page to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I think I have come across a classic back button issue with Bootstrap and I really tried looking around on the internet to find a solution but couldn't. 
I am using bootstrap nav pills.
I have about 8 pills and when I click on any of them, the page scrolls to that particular section and the URL changes to xyz.com/abc#sectionx
When I press the back button the URL changes to xyz.com/abc but the page doesn't scroll back to the top.

---****-----

Edit: I don't think I made this clear. 
The URL changes but the page remains on the same section xyz.com/abc#sectionx
Hence, if the user doesn't look at the URL, then they will think that pressing the back button had no effect.

---****-----

So I tried using this:

```
$('html,body').on('hashchange', function () {
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

But that didnt work, so I tried to define the value of Top in a different way:

```
$('html,body').on('hashchange', function () {
    var top = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
    $('body').scrollTop('top');
});
```

But that didnt work, so I tried:

```
$('html,body').on('hashchange', function () {
 if (window.scrollY>0) {
 window.scrollTo(0,window.scrollY-20)
 setTimeout("gototop()",10)
 }
});
```

I have also tried replacing `html, body` with `window` but that doesn't work either. 
I am really confused on what to do and how to go about making the back button take me to the top of the page. The thing is that the back button is changing the URL which is great but it also needs to scroll to the top. 
Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly valuable. I would highly appreciate guidance in jQuery or pure javascript.

Comment: Am I the only one who gets really irritated when websites mess with the back button? :(

Comment: Seconded. I wouldn't recommend doing this, as tons of people rely on the back button to do just that.

Comment: I personally think that leaving it like that is very un-intuitive. If you press the back button, you dont want the page to remain on the same section of the website. You want it to go where you previous were, which in this case is top of the page.

Comment: The back button should be for navigation between pages, not navigation within them. Many websites offer a floating up button once a user starts scrolling, I think this is worth pursuing rather than messing with a user's expectations

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by floating up button. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @DeekshaJuneja a button that is 'stuck' and floating on top of the content that says 'return to top' see example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_to_top)

Comment: Oh okay. I wouldnt like to implement that because I have seen many times that those set badly ruined on the mobile site, which I dont want.

Comment: @lloyd I tried to use the example you gave. It worked well on the website, and to my surprise on the iPhone but it broke on Android. On Android, you just get a button at the top of the page which doesnt scroll.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to scroll to the top. Consider either a floating button, or a link separating each section. As discussed above, generally users want the back button to do what's expected.

you can make a link easily enough with its own anchor like so.

```
<h2 id="top">Top of Page</h2>

// block of content

<a href="#top">Go to top</a>

// block of content

<a href="#top">Go to top</a>

.....
```

Comment: What do you think the users expect the back button to do? Because currently in my case, the back button doesnt do anything for a few clicks because the anchor links change the URL. So pressing the back button just changes the URL back but doesnt redirect you to any page. I was wondering whether that can be annoying for users.

Comment: Generally speaking the default behavior. I know it can be strange with anchor links since they just sort of port you around. If you want to get deep into it I suggest you check the [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), as I'm not an expert on UX.  [Here's a nifty post about the back button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/do-users-understand-the-browser-back-button)